# Merging shapefile layers not working in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, vector

How do i merge different vector layers in to one shapefile layer

In QGIS version 2.6

Answer (score 4):

Depending what exactly you want to do with the data, either:

(A) Keep each feature intact, including overlapping areas: Vector --> Data Management Tools --> Merge Shapefiles to One...

(B) Union to deal with overlaps: Vector --> Geoprocessing Tools --> Union

Comment: Thanks very much for your concern,Dealt with Condition (A) but am still having a problem that my new vector files i uploaded from Gps thaey can not merge in to One Major shape file,Condition (B) i haven't understand it

Comment: GPX files contain points, routes and tracks, divided into three layers by QGIS. Since the Merge tool is an external command, you might have to translate them into shapefile format first. Or use copy&paste.

Comment: @AndreJ,i have tried that by saving as a shape file but it takes only one route.Howw can u help me please

Comment: There are probably programmatic ways to do this, but if you want a GUI, I usually use this program to export tracks, then work with them as features: http://www.dnr.state.mn.us/mis/gis/DNRGPS/DNRGPS.html

Comment: Thanks@Dan and @Andrej,am mostly pleased for your concern i managed to create one large shape file,apreciate your help all of you,expecting more from you

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the `Merge` tool, the underlaying datasources must have the same projection, and must have the same datatype (point/line/polygon).

You can use `Save As...` on one of your layers to create a new shapefile with the CRS of the other layer.

Copy and paste should work too if you set the target layer to edit mode.

Comment: +1 for specifying projection issues. I usually have project-specific data in the same projection and don't run into this. Good point.

Comment: Copy/paste best answer so far